# Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When trying to return a simple set of results from my database table 'checklist' I receive the following error;

**"Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given"**

The code of my list.php file is as follows;

```
<?php
require_once('/includes/connection.inc.php');
// create database connection
$conn = dbConnect('read');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM checklist ORDER BY created DESC';
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
?>

<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

<?php echo $row['created']; ?>
<?php echo $row['title']; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

The contents of my connection.inc.php file (for reference) is as follows;

```
    <?php 
        function dbConnect($usertype, $connectionType = 'mysqli') { 
          $db = 'projectmanager'; 
          $host = 'localhost'; 
          if ($usertype  == 'read') { 
            $user = 'root'; 
            $pwd = ''; 
          } elseif ($usertype == 'write') { 
            $user = 'root'; 
            $pwd = ''; 
          } else { 
            exit('Unrecognized connection type'); 
          } 

                // Connection goes here...
                  if ($connectionType == 'mysqli') {
    return new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
  } elseif ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
  }

    }

    ?>
```

I've been trying to follow some examples out of a book PHP Solutions: Dynamic Web Design Made Easy found [HERE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232498) ...but I already had an issue with the connection.inc.php file (snippet shown above) where I had to correct "or die ('Cannot open database');" and replace it with the IF based statement you see above for the mysqli_error. So I am wondering if this book is riddled with some basic, fundamental errors - at least that when presented to novices like me leave us baffled.

Any help guys?

Thank you

Comment: I looked at that thread first before posting and tried to make some modifications but obviously didn't quite 'get it' until Spudley chimed in below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is because you're combining object-oriented and non-OO calls to the MySQLi library.

The `mysqli_error()` function does indeed require a parameter -- it requires the connection variable; in your case, `$conn`.

```
mysqli_error($conn)
```

Howwever, if you'd written it in an OO manner, as you have done for most of the rest of the database calls, you would have written it like this:

```
$conn->error
```

Since all the rest of your code is written using object-oriented calls, it would make sense to use it for this call as well.

So your full line of code would look like this:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
```

You can see further examples in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Hope that helps.

With regard your question about the book you're using: I can't comment directly on the book itself as I haven't read it. But note that there are two MySQL libraries for PHP; the older `mysql` library, and the newer `mysqli` library. The older library also has a `mysql_error()` function, which differs from the newer one in that it does not require a connection variable. If there is an error in the book you are using, this may be the source of the confusion.

Comment: Hi Spudley, that worked! I didn't know that was the issue at all and I think the book has me slightly confused (now) but thanks for clearing that up. Appreciated.

Comment: About your *"I think the problem you're having is because you're combining object-oriented and non-OO calls to the MySQLi library."* - That shouldn't be a problem. It's not recommended, ok... but they do work together. Here, have a look for yourself https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php where the manual states under "Mixing styles": *It is possible to switch between styles at any time. Mixing both styles is not recommended for code clarity and coding style reasons.*. Btw; I only stumpled upon this question from a Google search about something I was looking for.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes, you're quite right. It is perfectly possible to mix the two styles. It's not good, but it can be done. The point of this answer was that doing so was confusing the OP, and was thus the cause of their problem. In and of itself it isn't wrong, but it was the reason that this person got confused. That's what I answered, and the answer helped them understand.